# Cannot create "New Team Project" in TFS 2008 after single-server hardware restoration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Our old TFS server went offline and in order to continue operation, I was tasked to restore the server on a new machine.  I followed the MSDN Howto (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and have been able to connect to the TFS and bring up the Work Items and Source Control folders from Team Explorer as a local user and a remote user.

When I login locally on the installation account (see below), I am able to expand and view the documents folder on a given project.  The Reports folder, however, has the red "X" icon.  When I login remotely on the installation account, both Document and Reports have the red "X" icon.  I'm also unable to select "Show Project Portal" since this is grayed out from the menu.

I am also unable to create a new team project as described in the title whether I login locally or remotely.  I've been at this issue for about two weeks now and cannot seem to find a solution.  Appreciate any help.

Here is the error message I get after trying to add a new project:

Error
TF30224: Failed to retrieve projects from the report server. Please check that the SQL Server Reporting Services Web and Windows services are running and you have sufficient privileges for creating a project.

Explanation
The Project Creation Wizard encountered a problem while creating reports on the SQL Server Reporting Services on NEWTFSSERVER. The reason for the failure cannot be determined at this time. Because the operation failed, the wizard was not able to finish creating the SQL Server Reporting Services site.

User Action
Contact the administrator for the SQL Server Reporting Services on NEWTFSSERVER to confirm that the SQL Server Reporting Services server is running and you have sufficient privileges to create a project . Your user account on SQL Server Reporting Services must have Content Manager permission to create a new project. Also, you might find additional helpful information in the project creation log. The log shows each action taken by the wizard at the time of the failure and may include additional details about the error.

Here are the main user accounts:

NEWTFSSERVER\TFSSETUP - TFS Installation Account 
NEWTFSSERVER\TFSSERVICE - TFS Service and Reporting Service account

Server 2003 - each have the following permissions (some arbitrarily granted):

Administrators,
IIS_WPG,
SQLServer2005ReportingServicesWebServiceUser,
SQLServer2005ReportServerUser,
TFS_APPTIER_SERVICE_WPG,
Users,
WSS_ADMIN_WPG,
WSS_RESTRICTED_WPG

Report Manager - http://localhost/Reports/, TFSSETUP and TFSSERVICE are system administrators, system users, and have all item-level permissions including content managers.

SharePoint Central Admin v3 - TFSSETUP and TFSSERVICE are farm administrators and site collection administrators.

Team Foundation Server Global Group Membership - TFSSERVICE is a member of Service Accounts and TFSSETUP is a member of Team Foundation Server Administrators.

Team Foundation Server Project Group Membership - TFSSETUP is a member of Project Administrators.

New System Specs: 
Windows Server 2003 SP1 - Datacenter Edition,
SQL Server 2005,
VS 2008,
TFS 2008 SP1,
WSS 3.0

Comment: Just installed VS2008 SP1 on the server and I am able to view Reports!  The new server doesn't have Internet access, but I found out you can workaround this by using an ISO.

Comment: Now I am dealing with a TF30272 error: "Template Not Found on the Server".

Comment: Resolved this issue, but I am faced with another.  Tracking this here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/e2146564-eebc-4065-b6df-5c827ccb6578) since SO is not letting me answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely make certain that all of your clients are using VS 2008 with SP1. Also, I remember being frustrated because several of our developers installed VS 2008, applied SP1 and then installed Team Explorer. If you do in that order, you will have a Team Explorer without SP1. So make sure you install VS 2008, Team Explorer and then apply SP1.